# Convert NSDictionary containing NSArray to JSON

Tags: objective-c, json, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

I have a `NSDictionary` containing a few different objects, among which is a `NSArray`.

Elements in the array are `NSDictionary`-representations of a custom object. I have renamed the properties and removed some others for simplicity.

First I try to simply serialize the `NSArray` like this, just to see what it would look like:

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myArray options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&writeError];
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

The result looks like this, which is what I expected:

```
[
  {
    "someProperty" : "Value 1"
  },
  {
    "someProperty" : "Value 2"
  }
]
```

However, when I add the (unencoded) array to a `NSDictionary` and serialize that in stead the array looks different:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[myArray addObject:[object1 dictionaryRepresentation]]; // dictionaryRepresentation returns a NSDictionary
[myArray addObject:[object2 dictionaryRepresentation]];

NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dictionary setObject:myArray forKey:@"myArray"];
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&writeError];
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

Now the result looks like this:

```
{
  myArray =     (
                  {
            "someProperty" : "Value 1"
        },
                  {
            "someProperty" : "Value 2"
        }
  );
}
```

In stead of getting `"myArray" : [...]` I get `myArray = (...);` which is not the proper JSON representation.

What is the correct way of making it use the JSON representation of the `NSArray` when adding it to the dictionary?

Comment: The best (though not perfect) explanation for your screwy "Now" result is that you took the encoded JSON from the first dictionary, converted to NSString, and then added that to the second dictionary.  This is not how it should be done.  You should add the first dictionary itself, not its JSON representation, to the second dictionary.  Everything should be JSON-encoded at the same time, with a single operation.

Comment: (It would kinda help if you showed us the code doing the encoding, including the NSLog statements producing the above output.)

Comment: I believe that I understand the confusion now. It may have looked like I was taking the encoded representation of the `NSArray` (from the first code snippet) and adding it to my `NSDictionary` (in the second code snippet). In fact, the two code snippets are not being used together at all. As I explained in my question I only used the code in the first snippet to test what the serialization of an `NSArray` would look like. I have now provided additional lines of code to explain what it is that I am actually doing with the array. I apologize for the inclarity.

Comment: The point is that your final "JSON" listing above is not valid JSON, nor is it what one would see on NSLogging an NSDictionary that represents valid JSON.  Note that "myArray" is not quoted, and is followed by `=`, consistent with NSLog of a dictionary, while "someProperty" *is* quoted and is followed by `:`, consistent with JSON.  You're not showing us the real data.

Comment: (A JSON "object" contains quoted key values and separates key from value with `:`.  An NSLog of an NSDictionary only quotes key values if they contain non-alpha characters, and separates key from value with `=`.  Also, a JSON "object' is "bracketed" by `[]`, while an NSLog of a dictionary brackets the dictionary with `()`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case, you are printing out the result of the JSON encoding operation.

In the second case, you are printing out the dictionary directly via `NSLog` and not its JSON representation.

**Update:**

To see this, use this logging function instead of `NSLog`:

```
void logThisObject(id obj)
{
    if(obj == nil) {
        NSLog(@"logObject: nil");
    } else {
        NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([obj class]);
        NSLog(@"logObject: an %@: %@", className, obj);
    }
}
```

**Update 2:**

```
void test_it()
{
    NSArray *myArray = @[@"bla", @"foo"];
    NSError *writeError = nil;

    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [dictionary setObject:myArray forKey:@"myArray"];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&writeError];
    if(writeError) {
        NSLog(@"an error happened: %@", writeError);
    }
    logThisObject([[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
}
```

this outputs proper JSON string:

```
logObject: an __NSCFString: {
  "myArray" : [
    "bla",
    "foo"
  ]
}
```

Comment: The second case is not *exactly* what you'd see from an NSLog of a dictionary/array, but I presume that the OP simply approximated the appearance of the results in that case.  The actual output would have `=` instead of `:` and would have no quotes around strings that did not contain any whitespace or non-alpha characters.

Comment: @HotLicks The second case is what I get from the code that I included. Elements in `myArray` are `NSDictionary`-representations of a custom object. I did however rename the properties and remove some others for simplicity.

Comment: @Michael What I am printing in the second case is the endoded JSON for the dictionary (convertet to a `NSString` of course). However, when I am adding the `NSArray` to a `NSDictionary` I assume it is using the same representation of the array which is used by `NSLog` so the result would look the same.
What I need to know is the correct way of making it use the JSON representation of the `NSArray` when adding it to the dictionary.

Comment: @NobleK: I updated my answer. It seems like you are JSON encoding a dictionary, throw away the result, and then print out the unencoded dictionary. Maybe you can reproduce the problem with one independent piece of code that I can copy-paste into Xcode?

Comment: @Michael Why do you say this? I am JSON encoding my dictionary and saving it into the `NSData` object `jsonData`. Then I print a string initiated with `jsonData`. How am I throwing anything away?
In any case, my problem is not with _endocing the dictionary_. It is with _making the array within that dictionary being JSON encoded_ in the process. I'm probably just missing an intermediate step.

Comment: @NobleK: because it's just true. I updated my answer again. Just post a complete function and its output, and I will tell you what's wrong with it ;)

Comment: @Michael - OK, I see what you've done.  You've erroneously embedded the encoded JSON of the inner dictionary into the outer dictionary, then dumped the outer dictionary with NSLog.

Comment: @HotLicks me? you mean NobleK, don't you? my code works.

Comment: I believe that I understand the confusion now. It may have looked like I was taking the encoded representation of the `NSArray` (from the first code snippet) and adding it to my `NSDictionary` (in the second code snippet). In fact, the two code snippets are not being used together at all. As I explained in my question I only used the code in the first snippet to test what the serialization of an `NSArray` would look like. I have now provided additional lines of code to explain what it is that I am actually doing with the array. I apologize for the inclarity.

Comment: so anyhow, why not use the function `logThisObject(obj)` instead of `NSLog(@"%@", obj)`? As I said, if you can provide a closed example, a function that I can copy&paste as-is into my Xcode and that reproduces the problem, I can tell you where the problem is.

Comment: Reviewing my code again today I have detected that you were in fact correct, since among my large amount of console logging I was actually looking at the wrong output. What I provided in the question (and what caused me to believe that there was an issue) did in fact come from a direct output of the `NSDictionary` rather then the JSON representation. I thank you for your help and apologize for my stubbornness.

Comment: Hello, I have the same issue what is posted but frankly the logging is not my problem but parsing by server to be specific the mentioned JSON conversion is expected as Dictionary -- (string parameter key value, string ...key value, key parameter where value is nsarray of dictionary) But when i compose this as one dictionary and then give for JSON conversion its not working, either ';' or [ or , is mis calculated for JSONserialisation.

Comment: {
  "metadata" : "{\n  \"expire_date\" : \"2216-03-02 11:37:20\",\n  \"template_id\" : \"CMT002\",\n  \"title\" : \"\",\n  \"who_can_see\" : \"0\",\n  \"sub_title\" : \"\",\n  \"who_can_share\" : \"2\"\n}",
  "timestamp" : "2016-03-02 11:37:29",
  "user_id" : "982",
  "contents" : "[\"{\\n  \\\"content_value\\\" : \\\"TEST DATA 123\\\",\\n  \\\"content_type\\\" : \\\"1\\\"\\n}\"]",
  "shared_users" : ""
}